# How to do with fzz file

Tags: arduino-yun

I have a file YunConfig.fzz file for arduino yun for map maker project with ultrasonic sensor.
How can I open or do with that file?
please answer me.

Comment: That's a fritzing drawing.

Comment: Have a look at Fritzing.org.  With most unknown files you can use a text editor (Notepad) to look at the file.  Sometimes the file will be text and you might be able to read it.  The rest of the time it will be binary and it will look like garbage, however there might be some strings in there that give you a clue as to what application the file is for.

Comment: BTY, the Fritzing CAD software is not free. it is 9$ US.

Answer (score 5):

Download and install the open-source, [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/home/) CAD software for electronics hobbyist and open the .fzz file with that.

Versions are available for Linux, Mac, and Windows.

Installation instructions are on the [downloads](http://fritzing.org/download/) page.

Comment: Fritzing does no longer seem to be free (as in beer) and it's quite hard to compile [the sources](https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-app), IMHO

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest version here:
fritzing(dot)org/download/api/1.0/update/344
or find a version on softpedia

Comment: The Fritzing download is no longer available. Softpedia Link: https://www.softpedia.com/get/Science-CAD/Fritzing.shtml